# Is there any equivalent to watchman(availabe in nodeJS npm library) on Windows?

Tags: node.js, windows

As I know Watchman is only available for Mac Os. It is a simple utility that watches files/directories for changes and performs an action when they change.

Answer (score -1):

Try [nodemon](https://nodemon.io/).

I also developed a similar script a while ago - [simplemon](https://github.com/mihaifm/simplemon). I'm not sure if it works with the latest node version.