# What do I do now that watchman is deprecated?

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

https://www.npmjs.com/package/watchman

This was the only fix to npm start not working for react native. Is there a way to force this to install even though its deprecated?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42861655/14419

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I should be using the react native cli package and not the create react native app package. If you are experiencing issue with react native I recommend you use the command below to install react native to your package.json

```
npm install react-native-cli --save
```

Use the command below to make your react native app.

```
react-native init appName
```

And from there it will build the app and as long as you have Android Studio set up properly you can can easily call

```
react-native run-android
```

to start your app in the emulator.